# I created a domain name from cloudflare, and Hoisted my static site hosted in google firebase, error in adding custom domain in firebase

Tags: firebase, dns, cloudflare, hoisting

One or more of Hosting's HTTP GET request for the ACME challenge failed: 2606:4700:3030::ac43:9347: Too many redirects, 2606:4700:3034::6815:319f: Too many redirects

Comment: I voted to close this question because is about debugging a problem but has no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).